# How to return array item after converted by pressing a key

Tags: javascript

I'm building a game and I've done this:

```
var names=["Adam Black", "Brad White"];
var namePicked = var namePicked = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)]; //pick a random name
var nameArray = namePicked.split(""); //turn name string into array of letters
var nameHidden = [];

window.onload = function() {

    //replace each of the letters with underscore and space with dash
    for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
        if (nameArray[i] == " ") {
            nameHidden += "- ";
        }
        else {
            nameHidden += "_ ";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = nameHidden;
}

//get key pressed by user
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    nameArray = nameArray.map(function(x) {return x.toLowerCase()}); //lowercase all letters so uppercase letters get caught when key pressed

    // check letter entered with letters of names
    for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
        if (charStr == nameArray[i]) {
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm stuck here. How to switch/replace the values back to letters?

for example: "Adam Black" will be converted to 4 underscores 1 dash and 5 underscores, and when the user presses key a, both letter a will show up:
A _ a _ - _ _ _ _

I can't change the `nameHidden[i]` back to `nameArray[i]` when the right key is pressed. I can get the value of the key pressed with console.log.

I've tried loops, new var, boolean...

Also, how can I make sure when a key is presesd (ie "a"), the user can press it again but nothing happens?

Comment: can you not just say nameHidden[i] = nameArray[i]; document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = nameHidden; within your if statement

Comment: Thank you all of you for your suggestions. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not that far off, but it would be easier to make the part that updates the HTML into a function, and just call that function with the given character, something like

```js
var names      = ["Adam Black", "Brad White"];
var namePicked = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)]; //pick a random name
var nameArray  = namePicked.split(""); //turn name string into array of letters
var updated    = []; // keep track of values that are already updated

function display(char) {
  //replace each of the letters with underscore and space with dash
  char = char || '_';   // set to default when no char given
  var nameHidden = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    if (updated[i] || (char.toLowerCase() === nameArray[i].toLowerCase())) {
      nameHidden += nameArray[i];
      updated[i] = true;
    } else if (nameArray[i] == " ") {
      nameHidden += "- ";
    } else {
      nameHidden += "_ ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = nameHidden;
}

//get key pressed by user
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  display(charStr); // call when typing
});

display(); // call onload
```

```html
<div id="nameDisplay"></div>
<br /><br /><br />
<p>Focus here, and hit keys !</p>
```

Comment: Amazing! This is the solution I was looking for. Thank you @adeneo.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to define a function that converts a regular name into a hidden name (with the underscores and dashes), knowing the characters that have been pressed in an array.

```
function convertToHidden(name, charsPressed) {
    var hiddenName = "";
    // iterate over each character in the |name| string
    for (var n=0; n<name.length; n++) {
        var currCharInName = name[n];
        // now check if that character has been pressed
        var hasBeenPressed = false;
        for (var p=0; p<charsPressed.length; p++) {
            if (charsPressed[p] == currCharInName) hasBeenPressed = true;
        }
        if (hasBeenPressed) hiddenName += currCharInName;
        else hiddenName += "_";
        hiddenName += " ";
    }
    return hiddenName;
}
```

Then you could use this in the keypress function like so:

```
var charsPressed = [];
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    if (! charsPressed.includes(charStr)) charsPressed.push(charStr);
    var nameHidden = convertToHidden(namePicked, charsPressed);
    // display |nameHidden|
}
```